# Magento jscript login window appearing even after user logged in

Tags: magento

I'm using jscript login for my magento store. The problem is even after logged in also the login window is appearing... I have used onload="showSmartLoginDialog(); inside my homepage templates body tag. Plz guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional code around your body tag in your template.  Try this instead of `<body>`:

```
<?php
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { 
        echo '<body>';
    } else {
        echo '<body onLoad="showSmartLoginDialog()">';
    }
?>
```